# Styling an ordered list, and putting the numbers inside the list item

Tags: html, css, web, html-lists

I'm wondering if it's possible to do accomplish an effect similar to the screenshot below using `<ol>` in HTML.

I want each white bubble to be a `<li>` in the `<ol>`, that way if I change their order in the HTML, the numbers will update automatically. I cant figure out how to put the number inside the list item itself, and to prepend "Example #" before it.

[image: Example of what I want to do]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [CSS `counters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) for this.

```
body {
  counter-reset: section;                   /* Set the section counter to 0 */
}
h3::before {
  counter-increment: section;               /* Increment the section counter*/
  content: "Section" counter(section) ": "; /* Display the counter */
}
```

Comment: Counters is the best suited for this one because the counter value can also be used for the content. +1

Comment: You can do this with the ol/li, without ::before or ::after, but I believe it only works on mozilla.